# Twitter Bootstrap fluid container including maxwidth elements

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Simple question : i'd like to see inner elements with their maximized widths.
**P.S.** I'm using Twitter Bootstrap 3.3.0. which supports .container-fluid

```
<div class="row form-group form-inline">
   <div class="container-fluid">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="1">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="2">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="3">
   </div>
</div>
```

Elements seems okay, i just want each of them to share %33.3 of a row with their widths.
**Additional info** : i don't want to try following example, because there's so much space between

```
<div class="row form-group form-inline">
   <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="col-sm-2">
         <input type="text" class="form-control" name="1">
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-2">
         <input type="text" class="form-control" name="2">
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-2">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="3">
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `col-sm-xx` directly to the input fields won't work, because bootstrap itself will override the width with `width:auto`.

You need to put the inputs in columns. It's `col-sm-4` for `33%` of the parent container. Also, the inputs need `100% width` to fill the whole column.

```css
.form-inline [class*=col] {
  padding: 0;  
}
.form-inline input.form-control {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row form-group form-inline">
   <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="col-sm-4">
         <input type="text" class="form-control" name="1">
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
         <input type="text" class="form-control" name="2">
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="3">
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what about <select> fields ? 
.form-inline input.form-control, select.form-control {
    width: 100%;
} doesn't work for me.